# Initialize angular variable on opening a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with 2 different sets of data (what I mean here is I have a checkbox on the page, it will display User1 details when the checkbox is checked else it will display User2 details). I am binding the checkbox values using AngularJS.

My requirement is, I should have a button which will open the same page in a new window but different settings (checkbox is checked in this case). How will I achieve this?

Following is what I have in mind, we can open the new window using the following and add a hidden var which enables or disables the checkbox.

var myWindow = window.open("Page_URL");

I am pretty sure the above is not an optimum solution, can anyone give me a good solution for my requirement?

Comment: angular is used for a SPA = single page application so you're basically throwing that out the window, second you can use localstorage/sessionstorage to preserve the data between pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value in url itself. Please find the various way below,

1. Using Query Param

> "Page_URL/?value="+checkBoxValue
>   Ex:localhost:8080/project/home?value=checked

2. Using $stateprovider or $routeProvider

> $routeProvider.when('/home/:value', {
>      template: 'home.html',
>      controller: 'homeController'
>     });

then from controller,you can pass the value to url

> $location.path('home/'+checkboxValue)
>
> Note: Basically we need to avoid usage of localstorage/sessionStorage
>   as per best practices.

Comment: Thanks. Basically I am using asp.net mvc for routing, I will follow your idea and implement the same in asp.net.